# Attach picture with timestamp after timestamp timeframe has passed android intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I am developing an insurance app for a local company and I have the basics down for capturing an accident photo with timestamp and saving to directory with no issues.

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM/Camera");

File image = new File(imagesFolder, "ACCIDENT_PHOTO_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

private void PictureApp() {
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Now I want to attach and send this picture but how do I implement the "timestamp" into the Uri.from.File if the actual timestamp timeframe has passed?

Here is my current intent to send the accident photos:

```
private void SharePicApp() {
        final Intent ei = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        ei.setType("image/jpeg");
        ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email@gmail.com"});
        ei.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "LMR Accident Photos");

        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagesFolder, "ACCIDENT_PHOTO_" + timeStamp + ".jpg")));

        ei.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ei, "Sending Accident Photos"), 12345);
}
```

Comment: *"after timestamp timeframe has passed"* could you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: As in if I take the picture at 10:35am and try to attach the picture at 10:36am the "timestamp" has passed and the attach intent can not find the picture due to the timestamp = timeframe = 10:35am has passed.  Hope this explains a bit more.  Thanks a ton for any input.

Comment: I think you have a very flawed design there if, when sending an mail, you are looking for attachments based on the current time. So my recommendation is: Revisit your design and think how to solve this in a more elegant way...

Comment: Thanks Ben.  Yes I was looking into adding an incremental _1 _2 _3 to the end of the timestamp but I am not sure how to implement the incremental code for naming the picture:   File image = new File(imagesFolder, "ACCIDENT_PHOTO_" + timeStamp + "_1" + ".jpg");